# In Excel using VBA how do I split multiple values seperated by different seperators (ie: commas, colons, etc)

Tags: vba, excel, split

I am pulling data from the web into an excel spreadsheet.  All data is listed in column A, Sheet1. ex:

```
Name: Smith John A.

License: General - Master

License Status: Active

City/State: Anytown, USA

County: Thatoneyouknow

Contact Information

Cell Phone: (555) 555-555

Email Address: johnsmith@johnsmith.com

Region: One

Ever Been Disciplined?: No

Notes: None
```

And it then repeats similar info for the next person right after, etc.

I have been able to split the text by the colon that separates the data using the code below:

```
Sub DataReOrganizer()
Dim s1, s2 As Worksheet
Dim Cook, i, K As Long
Dim v As String
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Cook = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
K = 2
For i = 1 To Cook
      v = s1.Cells(i, "A").Text
      If v = "Contact Information" Then
          K = K + 1
      Else
          ary = Split(v, ": ")
          If ary(0) = "Name" Then s2.Cells(K, 1) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "License" Then s2.Cells(K, 2) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "License Status" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "City/State" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "County" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "Home Phone" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "Work Phone" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "Cell Phone" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "Email Address" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "Region" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "Ever Been Disciplined?" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = ary(1)
          If ary(0) = "Note" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = ary(1)
      End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

This works well so far by taking the data, separating the values into different columns with each new row as the next person in the list on sheet2.  However, to simplify things, is it possible to convert this code to separate the names by the commas too, same with the license field, but by the hyphen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just do another split on ary(1)

Comment: Instead of splitting for the first event, use `Like`. Ex. `If v Like "Name*" then`...  You can then split from the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you wanted separate cells for a first name and last name, since you want to split it, but you can change `'YourRange` below if that is the case. You do not need to split the original string to an array, simply use `Like`, and the wildcard `*`.

```
Sub DataReOrganizer()

    Dim s1, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim Cook, i, K As Long
    Dim v As String
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Cook = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 2
    For i = 1 To Cook
        v = s1.Cells(i, "A").text
        If v = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            If v Like "Name:*" Then
                'YourRange = Split(Split(v, ":")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
                s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(v, ",")(1)               'First Name
            End If
            If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(v, "-")(1)
            If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ":")(1)
            If v Like "Note:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ":")(1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

You have a few options when using `Split()`. Commonly, it's used to add the splits to an array, such as you did. But you can skip the array altogether and return a single string by adding `(i)` to the end of the split. Example, if `i = 0`, you would return the entire string *prior* to the first delimiter. Likewise, `i = 1` would return the entire string after the first delimiter, `i = 2` would return everything after the 2nd, so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great!  I did/was going to split the first and last name, thank you for including that with you answer.  However, I am now struggling to separate the middle initial (if one exists).  It isn't a big issue, I can leave the middle initial, but for my edification, how would I achieve that split?  The middle initial is separated from the last name by a space and always ends with a period. ex: "John Smith A."

Comment: You could do another split on the first name, using space `" "` as the delimiter. You could even check to verify it an initial using `If Len() = 1`. I forgot to add an explanation as to what the (1) after the splits were for, so I will update the answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Perfect, this was such a great help and great explanation.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could do another split - not sure about name as there is no comma - but for licence. Incorporating a check that hyphen exists as suggested by @Sorceri. Strictly speaking you should do the same for colons too.

```
  If ary(0) = "License" Then
     s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(ary(1), "-")(0)        
     If InStr(ary(1), "-") > 0 Then
        s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(ary(1), "-")(1)
    End If
  End If
```

Comment: you should add a check to ensure there is a hyphen or comma